# How to convert style text to C# class/hashTable/collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, regex-negation

I have style text like this one:

```
".abc {border: 1px solid blue;color:black;...} 
.abc{background-image:url('http://example.com/images/a.png')...}
#abcd {color: blue}..."
```

I need to edit this text in the server (change background-image or add color property... ) and then save it as text.

I think the best way is to convert this text to a c# object such class/hashTable/collection

may be with regular expression ??

can some one help me with this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: By save it as text do you mean change the style sheet so the changes are rendered?

Comment: no,I need to save it to the DB ....
later on when the user will request it I will need to render this style

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not the best tool for parsing languages.

There's a lot of CSS parsers out there, taking the first link from Google - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335850/CSSParser

However, if you're working e.g. on templating, dynamic style-sheets etc., that's probably not the best way to do it. You might want to use some CSS framework such as SASS.

And of course, the best way to change parts of CSS is to simply append the classes you want to the bottom of the file (or in a separate file altogether).

Answer (score 0):

Parsing seems like overkill for this requirement.

Given that you will have one or two states -- a known beginning -- that is the css before any edits or a set of edits already saved, parsing the CSS seems un-needed.  You can just hard code the starting state and read the prior values if the user has made changes.